# Which fraction is greater $ \frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta} \quad \textrm{or} \quad \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$

Tags: real-analysis

Which fraction is greater $$ \frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta} \quad \textrm {or} \quad \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$ $ 0<\alpha<\beta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

and why?

Comment: What have you tried?  How about making expressions in only $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Maybe Taylor  series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\tan\gamma}\gamma$$ is a growing function in the first quadrant.

Hence

$$\alpha<\beta\implies\frac{\tan\alpha}\alpha<\frac{\tan\beta}\beta\implies\frac{\tan\alpha} {\tan\beta}<\frac\alpha\beta.$$

Comment: In particular, $\operatorname{tanc}^\prime\gamma=\frac{1-\operatorname{sinc}2\gamma}{\gamma\cos^2\gamma}$.